# Eclipse doesn't compile *.C with gcc

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc

I am using Eclipse Kepler and running it under Win7 64-Bit. As compiler I use the gcc (4.8.1) from MinGW. Now I have the following problem:

**//edit: Reformulated question to make it more clear**

I have a project containing of one source-file with C-Code: `main.c`

This file can be compiled over 2 ways:

1. Start the compiler over the command-line: `gcc -o main.exe main.c`
2. Start the compiler over Eclipse by starting the normal build-routine (which also calls the `gcc`)

Now for some reason I want to add some C++-Code, but I still want to compile it with the `gcc`.

The `gcc` itself decides how to compile over the file extension - This means, if `main.c` contains C++-Code and I call `gcc -o main.exe main.c` it won't work. To make the compiler realize it's C++ I have to change the file-extension to somthing like `.C` or `.cpp` and then it will work.

Now back to Eclipse:

When I change my Sourcefile to `main.C` Eclipse interprets it as C++ File, meaning it changes the Code-Highlighting. When I now start a build process over Eclipse it just tells me

`Info: Nothing to build for PROJECT`

This means there is not even a call to the `gcc`-compiler. My guess is, that Eclipse somehow doesn't want to call the gcc, because the source-file is marked as C++-File.

**//edit2:** Just tried - when I have a C++-Projekt Eclipse just ignores the `*.C` or the `*.cpp`-files. I guess I have to add them manually, so they're built too ... but where?

Comment: This is very close to being off-topic, I think, since it's more about some very specific behavior of Eclipse's, rather than actual programming.

Comment: @unwind but too specific isn't offtopic for SO anymore.

Comment: @Toby try to exclude adn reinclude fiel to project?

Comment: @Zaibis - Yes, but that isn't necessary at all - Eclipse notices the change of the extension, which means when I have the *.c-extension it highlights code C-compliant and when I change it to `*.C` it changes to C++-compliant Code highlighting. This means when I leave it to `*.c` the Code-Highlighting is terrible and also, I need to rename the file with a C++ extension, so the gcc can compile it (ok I could also use the compiler flag for that, but then theres still the problem with code highlighting).

Comment: My guess is that Eclipse looks at the date modified of the file, which may not change if you simply rename it, thus doesn't think it should rebuild it. That said, your problem description isn't particular clear, so my assumptions about the problem you're having may be incorrect.

Comment: @Dukeling Updated question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

The `g++` is the compiler to compile `C++` codes.
Change you compiler in you eclipse project.

Comment: You'r false. GCC means "GNU Compiler Collection" and contains also C++ compiler!

Comment: @Bijaya Bidari - The problem is not the compiler itself (GCC is able to compile C++-Code) - my problem is the fact that Eclipse doesn't invoke the GCC and just tells me "Nothing to do" when I mark it as C++-Code

Comment: @Zaibis: The `gcc` command is used to compile C code. The `g++` command is used to compile C++ code. Both are provided by GCC.